# Infinite dimensional intermediate subfields of an algebraic extension of an algebraic number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $K$ be an algebraic number field, i.e. a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.
>   Let $L/K$ be an infinite dimensional algebraic extension of $K$.
>   Are there infinitely many *infinite* dimensional intermediate subfields of $L/K$?

It's easy to see that there are infinitely many *finite* dimensional intermediate subfileds of $L/K$, but I have no idea about the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. Clearly it is possible for there to be infinitely many subfields of infinite degree, take $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}/\mathbf{Q}$ for example. On the other hand, there exist infinite extensions of any number field $K$ with **no** intermediate fields of infinite degree over $K$.

For a concrete example, if $L = K_\infty/K$ is a $\mathbf{Z}_p$-extension (i.e. its Galois group is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_p$, the $p$-adic integers). Such an extension always exists, e.g. as a finite index subfield of $K(\mu_{p^\infty})$, the field given by adjoining all $p$-power roots of unity. Since $\mathbf{Z}_p$ has no nontrivial closed subgroups of infinite index, the fundamental theorem of Galois theory implies that there are no intermediate fields of infinite degree over $K$.

Comment: Your answer is precise and neat! +1 for that.

Comment: @Carter: I have asked a question arising out of your answer. Please look at that: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186295/big-intermediate-fields-in-an-infinite-tower

Answer (score -1):

Consider the set $P$ of prime numbers. The number of infinite subsets of $P$ it self is infinite, in fact uncountable. For each such infinite subset $A\subset P$
consider the extension of $K_A$ obtained by adjoining all square roots $\surd p,\ p\in A$. It can be shown that they are all distinct subfields. %K% itself may contain atmost a finite number of square roots of $p$, but it will not affect. (For example, to start with we can redefine $P$ to the *infinite* set of primes such that $\surd p$ is not in $K$).

Comment: How do you prove that $K_A \subset L$?

Comment: I misunderstood the question: the construction I gave merely gives one example of infinite extension containing infinitely many subextensions.